# How many Telegram public channels can have one account?

Tags: telegram

I'm going to create tens of public channels but I can't... At the moment I have **8 public channels**, and when I try to create a new one, I see this error:

[image]

**(1)** I was searching something like "telegram public channels maximum" through Google but I didn't find anything...

I didn't find anything here:

https://telegram.org/faq_channels

https://telegram.wiki/generalfaq/channels

**(2)** I asked their support but didn't get an answer as well.

Comment: We can't provide support for 3rd-party applications or software - we have no knowledge of their backend systems and the specifics. Any answers to such questions can only be speculation. For such support please contact the developer through the official channels.

Comment: @tambre I use official Telegram apps :)

Comment: And? We aren't the developers of that app and thus we're unable to provide such support.

Comment: @tambre I know.

Comment: Then why are you asking here? It's off-topic per the rules.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR:** You can create **10** public channel/group pre account now.

It was **5** when the channel is introduced in [Sep 2015](https://telegram.org/blog/channels).

Increased to **8** at [Jul 2017](https://t.me/tgbeta/1907).

Recently it increased to **10** in [Jul 2019](https://t.me/tgbeta/3733).

Comment: Thanks. A weird limitation :)

Comment: Now 10 reserved usernames per account. It's not weird but a good feature to avoid spamming and making username reservation limited to one account. You can however use a burner number to create a new account to reserve those usernames, but it's a little bit tiresome to manage it.